# Angular uiRouter nested state doesn't change html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a method called `processParams` that should change the `ui-view` of the page by calling `this.state.go('coupons.login')`. This loads a nested state of `coupon` which the user should already be inside of. Although `this.state.go...` is called, it never changes the `ui-view`. Why isn't it changing and how can I fix it?

#### Router file

```
'use strict';

angular.module('couponGeneratorApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('coupons', {
        url: '/generate-coupon',
        template: '<coupons></coupons>'
      })
      .state('coupons.login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '<h1>hello</h1>'
      });
  });
```

#### Controller File

```
'use strict';
(function() {

    class CouponsComponent {
        constructor($state) {
            this.test = 'hello';
            this.state = $state;

            this.couponParams = {};
        }

        processParams() {
            if (!this.couponParams.amount || this.couponParams.amount <= 0) {
                alert('Enter a valid amount');
            } else if (this.couponParams.has_min && (!this.couponParams.min_order || this.couponParams.min_order < 0)) {
                alert('Enter a valid min order');
            } else {
                this.state.go('coupons.login');
            }
        }
    }


    angular.module('couponGeneratorApp')
        .component('coupons', {
            templateUrl: 'app/coupons/form.html',
            controller: CouponsComponent
        });

})();
```

Comment: I think first state should be `abstract: true`

Comment: Didn't help. Still does nothing